# AuthorizeAttribute & POST Async

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I inherited a project that is WEB API in .NET 4.6 framework.  It implements custom authentication through the use of `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` such as:

```
public class AuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
   public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
   {
        //Call authentication logic against DB.
   }
}
```

I myself want to improve this to use the new JWT Token, so I went and wrote a .NET Core project that generates and returns a JWT token upon successful authentication.  I tested this piece using Postman to POST to the controller and it works.

Now, in my current code I want to invoke that WEB-API call inside the OnAuthorization() such as follow:

```
public class AuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
   public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
   {
        var auth = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;
        string[] userInfo = Encoding.Default.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(auth.Parameter)).Split(':');

        Profile user = new Profile();
        user.UserName = userInfo[0];
        user.Password = userInfo[1];

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:31786");
        var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/token/request", user);

        //I hope to get the JWT Token back here or by this time the server should return it or set it in a cookie.

        return "OK";
   }
}
```

But I can't get this to work, the response.Status is returning "WaitingForActivation".

I know why I'm getting this because I should change this call to have await and update the function's signature to Task.

```
await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/token", content);
```

However, I'm not able to do this because of the restriction from `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute`.  What can I do here, is there a way to still invoke an async call from within here or do I have to move my logic to somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a problem if you use the correct overload:

```
public override async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken token)
{
    var auth = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;
    string[] userInfo = Encoding.Default.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(auth.Parameter)).Split(':');

    Profile user = new Profile();
    user.UserName = userInfo[0];
    user.Password = userInfo[1];

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:31786");
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/token/request", user);

    //I hope to get the JWT Token back here or by this time the server should return it or set it in a cookie.

    return "OK";
}
```

By the way, you should take out that `new HttpClient()` from there and reuse it instead.